# Open IOS application from asp .net MVC web application on button click

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net-mvc

I have `asp .net MVC` web application that is developed to be used on Ipad and I want to open an IOS application that is already installed on the same Ipad on a button click. Now, the button click will take me to the app store and from there I can click OPEN, but I want to direct the user to the app directly not app store. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

The app must have a uri-shema registration in the OS. Obviously the app must be installed on the device - or a redirect to a web-app should take place.

Your website's button, should be a hyperlink, obviously it can be styled as a button.

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text='hello'">send</a>
```

The above link will open whatsapp, and send "hello" to a selected contact.

Usually there are specific actions you can link to:

```
<app-schema>://<action>?<parameters>
```

See the targeted app for more info.

Other examples:

- clock-alarm://
- contact://
- ibooks://
- whatsapp://

Actual parameters depend on app.

If it's you're own app you want to open: you can add the uri schema registration  to your application. The way to do it depends per project type.

More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app)

[Here's quite a list of build in app schema's](https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/always-updated-list-ios-app-url-scheme-names-0184033/)